# How to stop waiting for async wrapper around TaskCompletionSource by timeout?

Tags: asynchronous, f#, task-parallel-library

Let's say I have some system "BlackBox" that I can't change, and I want to try do some work with it for 2 seconds, if it will not finish - stop and proceed with other appliation:

```fsharp
let log msg =
    let timestamp = (System.DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("o"))
    printfn "%s: %s" timestamp msg

type BlackBox() =
    let tcs = new System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSource<bool>()

    let work () = async {
        log "work started"
        let! result = tcs.Task |> Async.AwaitTask
        log "work finished"
        return result }

    member x.DoWork    () = work ()
    member x.SetResult () = tcs.TrySetResult(true)

let tryDoWork (box:BlackBox) = async {
    try
        log "operration starting with 2sec timeout"
        Async.RunSynchronously(box.DoWork(), timeout = 2000) |> ignore
        log "operration succeeded"
    with
    | ex -> log "operation timedout" }

let sut = BlackBox()
tryDoWork sut |> Async.Start
log "waiting 5sec before setting task result"
Async.Sleep 5000 |> Async.RunSynchronously
log "setting task result"
sut.SetResult() |> ignore
​
​
// Output is:
// ------------------------------------
// 2016-02-24T16:45:11.0302884Z: waiting 5sec before setting task result
// 2016-02-24T16:45:11.0302884Z: operration starting with 2sec timeout
// 2016-02-24T16:45:11.0351932Z: work started
// 2016-02-24T16:45:16.0322394Z: setting task result
// 2016-02-24T16:45:16.0351731Z: work finished
// 2016-02-24T16:45:16.0361528Z: operation timedout
```

Async.RunSyncronously with timeout throws TimeoutException after 2 seconds, but not in this situation as internally BlackBox is waiting for Task to be finished.

Comment: use a TCS (for example with an `'a option`) and set the `Some` result with from the black-result and the `None` using another timed `async` or `task` and finally just wait for it's wait-handle

Comment: note: this will of course not cancel/abort the longer task - if you need this then first try the cancellation-token (if you have one) - if not you have to go the (not recommended) `Task.Abort` route

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TCS (from @Carsten's comment) works for me as I have no access to BlackBox internals and can't change that without changing the whole design of the application and need mechanism to add timeout, the cancel for longer task is not required

Other proposed things were:

@kevin:

> [snippet by Eirik Tsarpalis](https://fsnotebook.net/notebook/fssnip-hx/Async_AwaitTask_with_timeouts)  and `Async.AwaitIAsyncResult`

and as @kevin noticed that reason for my example not working as expected is that

> RunSynchronously with a timeout relies on the given async being cancelable

one more thing I found also is [how to cancel non-cancelable async operations](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/10/05/how-do-i-cancel-non-cancelable-async-operations.aspx)